# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorization

Tags: authorization, aws-api-gateway

We have a Monolith Application and new Microservices are now getting added.
We need to add a Centralized Authorization mechanism for all the services.
For this we will use API Gateway and the existing Authorization service (which is based on JWT and is also hosted in AWS)

All the examples & documentation that i could find has API-Gateway with Lambda authorizer, whereas I want to use the existing Authorizer.
Can i bypass the Lambda & directly provide URL of my Authorization API to API Gateway?

Reason for wanting to avoid Lambda is that it will introduce an additional Hop, plus there could be issues of Cold startup.

Alternately I could have all the Services call the existing Auth service, but then there will be duplication of code.

Looking forward to your inputs

Thanks

Comment: Won't the custom authorizer API call be considered an additional call as well?

Comment: If you mean moving the Auth module into Lambda to avoid additional call.                                                
We have our current Authentication/Authorization module in a Spring boot application, so I was planning to keep it in the existing Application, at least to start with.  I think Spring boot application wouldn't be suitable for Lambda. Secondly we also have 2-factor authentication in place, so not sure if it can be achieved in the API-Gateway Lambda setup.

Comment: You can run a Spring Boot application in Lambda (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot), but this will have performance implications that are much larger than cold starting a function with a simple intermediary. I'm not sure about 2FA, this depends on your actual setup. However, since you use 2FA, Lambda startup time is even less of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway needs a very specific response format (a valid IAM policy) and therefore can't bypass Lambda as a custom authorizer. You will need a Lambda function as an intermediary between your endpoint and the existing authorization API.

Regarding the additional hop: Calling the Lambda authorizer won't add much latency, especially compared to the call to an API outside AWS.

Regarding the cold start time: There are many ways to mitigate this (see Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – [Part 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/) and [Part 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-2/)).

The easiest one however, without adding any additional cost, is writing the function in an interpreted language, e.g. Python or JavaScript.

Before prematurely optimizing, I would implement a simple solution and measure the actual impact on latency and customer experience. With that data you can then apply additional mechanisms to e.g. reduce cold start time.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.  I missed adding that the existing Authentication service is also hosted in AWS, so there will not be a call outside AWS.  Before moving to this architecture I wanted to be sure it is a suitable approach for us.  As per my reading I can gauge that it is one of the standard & recommended approach. Will however do POC as recommended